# Socket io not working after being deployed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm not getting an error but `io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected', socket.client.id);
});` doesn't seem to work when I deployed my application in Linode.

But in the development it's working fine.

**server.js** *( socket io )*

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = 8002;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected', socket.client.id); // triggering in the development
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
    console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
        '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname +
        '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
});
```

**client html** *( note: i change the localhost to my web app ip)*

```
  <script src="http://localhost:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and my application seem to be using the socket.io polling-xhr.js

[image]

I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: In your production environment, are you using the port in the url? Perhaps it is expecting socket.io to be on port 80.

Comment: @Porlune my server is listening to **port 8002** but my application is running on **port 82**

Comment: You can have it set up so that your express app uses the same http server as socket.io. Set it up that way then please let us know if it works.

Comment: If you don't want to set up socket.io on the same http server, you can use: socket.connect('http://localhost:8002'); on the client to set the socket io host manually.

Comment: @Porlune can you post your idea as an answer so i can follow you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will fix your particular problem, but in order to set up socket.io on the same port that your application uses you can configure it this way:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 80;

// the express app is registered with the server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// setup socket.io and register it with the server
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// tell the application to listen on the port specified
server.listen(port, hostname, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('server listening on: ', hostname, ':', port);
});
```

Now socket.io runs on the same port as your application.